# Xabber File Upload

Tags: ejabberd, asmack, smack-stack

First of all sorry for my bad english..

I gone through sample code of Xabber Android. Server is using Ignite server with XMPP protocol. In the repository of Xabber android there is file uploading code inside it. But it's not working. **HttpFileUploadManger** returning false to it's file transfer service.

In server side, both Jingle and SI protocols are implemented. But HttpFileUpload manger is throwing null for upload server.

Please help me to resolve this issue.. I will be very thank full to you..